# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable, type error

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my first stackoverflow thread and I have a doubt why of my codes do work and the other doesn't, it seems to be the same, I would appreciate any response, thanks!

**Not working code:**

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    longitud = len(sys.argv[1])
    numero = int(sys.argv[1])
    cadena = str(numero)
    if numero > 0 and numero < 10000:
        print("The length is:",longitud)
        for r in range(longitud):
            print("{:04d}".format(numero[::-1][r]) * 10 ** r)
    else:
        print("Error")
else:
    print("Error")
```

**Working code:**

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    longitud = len(sys.argv[1])
    numero = int(sys.argv[1])
    cadena = str(numero)
    if numero > 0 and numero < 10000:
        print("The length is:",longitud)
        for r in range(longitud):
            print("{:04d}".format(int(cadena[::-1][r]) * 10 ** r))
    else:
        print("Error")
else:
    print("Error")
```

The only change is on line 11, on the first block I put `format(numero)` and on the second one I put `int cadena`, but they're basically the same

```
numero = int(sys.argv[1])
cadena = str(numero)
```

Isn't `numero` the same as `int(cadena)`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting a portion of `cadena` and of `numero`, you can index into a `string` (`cadena`), but not an `int` (`numero`). You cannot select a part of an `int`. E.g.:

```
sys.argv == ['1232', '12324']
numero = int(sys.argv[1]) # numero == 1232
cadena = str(numero) # cadena == '1232'
```

you can select the 2nd and 3rd letter from a string (e.g. `cadena[1:4] == '23'`) but not the 2nd and 3rd letter from an int (e.g. `numero[1:4] == error`). ints aren't indexible, while string are.

EDIT: 
this should also work, and breaks down the order of what you are doing to `cadena` better:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    longitud = len(sys.argv[1])
    numero = int(sys.argv[1])
    cadena = str(numero)
    if numero > 0 and numero < 10000:
        print("The length is:",longitud)
        for r in range(longitud):
            str(cadena)
            cadena = cadena[::-1]
            cadena = cadena[r]
            cadena = int(cadena)
            print("{:04d}".format(cadena * 10 ** r))
    else:
        print("Error")
else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood wrongly your explanation, but I'm making cadena (string) an integer again, and cadena converted to integer is the same as numero, and one does work while the other doesn't

Comment: You're making `cadena` an int AFTER you index into it

Comment: Thanks sir, I guess I got it

Comment: see my edit and let me know if that helps you understand it more

Comment: @PaulitaSpain If this answered your question, you should accept it, and upvote.

Comment: Hello sir, I tried your code and I receive the next error: 

0003
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "44.py", line 11, in <module>
    cadena = cadena[::-1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @CalebGoodman I tried to upvote but it didn't let me, how can I close the thread? thanks

Comment: Hey I fixed it, sorry. Since the loop keeps using `cadena` you need to make it a `string` again after converting it to an `int`. In your example it's not needed, because you aren't overwriting the value of `cadena` Also, you can accept the answer, if your question is answered (the big check around the voting arrows)